# Intel Math Kernel Library for Deep Neural Networks installation issue on Unix

Tags: unix, build, intel-mkl, intel-dnn, intel-dl-frameworks

I tried installing Intel MKL-DNN with following error
external folder does not get created upon doing.

```
cd scripts && ./prepare_mkl.sh && cd ..
```

As per "Download and Build Source Code" in the [installation guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation).

Please check.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I had tried installing Intel MKL-DNN and it worked fine. The 'external' folder was created successfully.

Refer screenshot:
[MKL-DNN installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXzYP.png)

Regards,

Nikhila

Comment: Thanks, it might have been a permissions issue.